# How to show the inequation of two function on two different values

Tags: analysis, functions

Denote $v_1(\lambda)=\frac{(1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-1}{\sqrt{1+(1-\lambda)^2+((1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-1)^2}}$ and $v_2(\lambda)=\frac{1-\lambda}{\sqrt{2+(1+\lambda)^2}}$. The figure shows the curve of $v_1(\lambda)$(red line) and $v_2(\lambda)$(blue line). Let $\alpha$ satisfies $v_1(\alpha)=0$, then for a given $\beta \in [0,\alpha)$, how can I prove $v_2(\lambda)>v_1(\beta)$ for $\lambda \in [\beta,\alpha]$?

[image]

Comment: There appears to be a typo somewhere: If $\beta = 0$, then "$v_{2}(\lambda) > v_{1}(\beta)$ for $\lambda$ in $[\beta, \alpha]$" is incompatible with your graphs.

Comment: Your plot for $v_1(\lambda)$ looks wrong. I think that what your plot shows is the absolute value of $v_1(\lambda)$